# What defines “disgusting food” in Halacha

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, halacha-theory, food, yoreh-deah

According to Halacha, [one is prohibited from eating “disgusting” foods](https://www.torahmusings.com/2012/06/disgusting-behavior/) in a prohibition known as Bal Teshaktzu. My question is, how does Halacha define disgusting food? What are the criteria that Poskim use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch (Yoreh Deah 116) defines it as foods containing disgusting things:

> It is prohibited to eat food and drinks that a persons soul is disgusted by, such as drinks and food that have vomit or feces mixed with them, and rotten moisture and things like this. It is assur to eat and drink from dirty vessels that a person's soul is disgusted by them, like bathroom vessels and glass vessels that they let blood into. And he should not eat with dirty hands and on dirty vessels, since all of these fall into the prohibition of "Do not make your souls abominable"